# Convert a deeply nested list to csv in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to write a deep nested list (within list within list) to csv, but it always collapse my list and printed with ..., which im unable to retrieve the hidden values.

List is to store frames of videos, the list goes up to 5 layer ()-len of each layer, Video (no of videos) > 8 frames(8) > width(200) > height(200) > pixel of 3 channel (3)

I tried converting the list to data frame before writing it to csv but still unable to solve this problem.

> "[array([[[0.23137255, 0.26666668, 0.27058825],
> [0.23921569, 0.27450982, 0.2784314 ],
> [0.23529412, 0.27058825, 0.27450982],
> ...,
> [0.25882354, 0.29411766, 0.2901961 ],
> [0.25490198, 0.2901961 , 0.28627452],
> [0.25490198, 0.2901961 , 0.28627452]],

```
   [[0.20392157, 0.23921569, 0.24313726],
    [0.21568628, 0.2509804 , 0.25490198],
    [0.21568628, 0.2509804 , 0.25490198],
    ...,
    [0.26666668, 0.3019608 , 0.29803923],
    [0.26666668, 0.3019608 , 0.29803923],
    [0.2627451 , 0.29803923, 0.29411766]],

   [[0.1882353 , 0.22352941, 0.22745098],
    [0.2       , 0.23529412, 0.23921569],
    [0.20392157, 0.23921569, 0.24313726],
    ...,
    [0.27450982, 0.30980393, 0.30588236],
    [0.27058825, 0.30588236, 0.3019608 ],
    [0.27058825, 0.30588236, 0.3019608 ]],

   ...,
```

Comment: xMoo, welcome -- do you know what the data structure is? Is it a simple matrix (list of lists)?

Comment: im trying to store frames of videos, the list goes up to 5 layer ()-len of each layer, Video (no of videos) > 8 frames(8) > width(200) > height(200) > pixel of 3 channel (3)

Comment: Ahh, okay -- I'd really caution you against using csv for this unless there's a really compelling reason to do so. Most of us store frames as images and perhaps reference them in a json or other structure

If you don't strictly need the csv format I'd recommend storing the square images on your disk and storing a reference structure (Which could be a csv) that's something like:
`video_name, frame1, frame2, frame3...., frame8` where each frame column is a file location.

What I would likely do is store the references to the images in json as `video_name: [frames...]`

Comment: it's worth noting you can store an **almost** arbitrary structure as json (which is what I suspect you'll end up doing), but I would be remiss if I didn't recommend storing images as images

Answer (score 0):

I'd try one of the following:
dump the whole object into json:

```
import json
with open('my_saved_file.json', 'w+') as out_file:
    out_file.write(list_of_lists_of_lists, indent=2)
```

What I'd try is storing all of your images as images and reference them in an index (could be csv)

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

with open('reference.csv', 'w+') as out_csv:
    out_csv.write("video, frame_set, frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4, frame5, frame6, frame7, frame8\n")

    for video_no, video in enumerate(list_of_lists_of_lists):
        row = [video_no]
        for frame_set_no, frames in enumerate(video):
            for frame_no, frame in enumerate(frames):
                im = Image.fromarray(frame)
                frame_name = f"{video_no}-{frame_set_no}-{frame_no}.jpeg"
                row.append(frame_name)
                im.save(frame_name)
        out_csv.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

Comment: This may (or more likely may not) be a useful answer to your question, but it'll be easier to work it out than in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help Schalton! However I've decided to just save them as images ;/ I very appreciate your help